# Error updateDoc with arrayUnion in firestore in expo firebaseJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have this code

```
try {
  const id = Date.now();
  const obj = {
    id:id,
    user:user,
    company:company,
    role:role,
    transmission:transmission,
    miles:miles,
    oldCar:oldCar,
    payMile:payMile,
    treat:treat,
    homeTime:homeTime,
    orientation:orientation,
    text:text,
    score: Math.round(((treat * 5 + homeTime * 5 + orientation * 5 + overvall * 5 + mintenance * 5 + dispatchers * 5) / (5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5)) *10,) / 10,
    likes: [],
    job:job,
    firstCon:firstCon,
    gross:gross,
    equipment:equipment,
    drvPosition:drvPosition,
    overvall:overvall,
    mintenance:mintenance,
    dispatchers:dispatchers,
  }
  if (obj) {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "companies", company.key), {
      "Reviews": arrayUnion(obj),
      "maxReviews": company?.maxReviews ? parseInt(company?.maxReviews) + 1 : 0,
    })
    console.log("review sended");
  } else {
    throw new Error("review object is not defined");
  }
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error("Error send review:" + error?.message);
}
```

In development its good work, but in production write this error

> Error send review:Function arrayUnion() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document companies/zhVuyv94Y4FrRBbA0DdN)

I'm update firebase to last version.

I'm try change more and it don't helpful.

my pkg json

```
{
  "name": "track",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "expo": "~47.0.14",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.8.0",
    "expo-blur": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.4.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.0.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.17.0",
    "expo-random": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^10.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-inset-shadow": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-switch-toggle": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "typesense": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Im don't now where this error handled and i don't know how logging it in iOS.

But interesting in my Phone in prodaction it work good

and it error try after this if else check

```
if (obj) {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "companies", company.key), {
      "Reviews": arrayUnion(obj),
      "maxReviews": company?.maxReviews ? parseInt(company?.maxReviews) + 1 : 0,
    })
    console.log("review sended");
  } else {
    throw new Error("review object is not defined");
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdBqU.jpg)

Comment: Have you inspected `obj` to see which fields are `undefined`? We don't know what any of these fields contain but that sounds like the gist of it.

Comment: Do you want to say that he is swearing because of someone in the field inside obj?